# Using the comparison test check if the series given by $a_n = \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Using the comparison test check if the series given by $a_n =
> \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ converges

The most natural way to solve this problem appears to be the Integral Test. I already tried this and showed that this series does not converge. However, when I typed this problem on Wolfram, it said that - by comparison test - the series did not converge. My problem is that I cannot think of a series suitable for this comparison - do you have any ideas what one could use here?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may use
$$
\ln\left(\ln (n+1)\right)-\ln\left(\ln (n)\right)\le\frac{1}{n \ln(n)},\quad n\ge4.
$$

Comment: How would you prove this inequality ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: Right, this should have occurred to me !

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps that what Wolfram Alpha has in “mind” is Cauchy's condensation test. If your series converges, then the series$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{2^n\log(2^n)}=\frac1{\log 2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1n$$converges too. But it diverges (by the comparison test).